# VS Code - show sidebar or panel exclusively

Tags: visual-studio-code, sidebar

Is it possible to configure VS Code to hide Side Bar when Panel is shown and hide Panel when Side Bar is shown? I work on a laptop so the screen estate is at premium. Thus I would like to have both Side Bar and Panel on the right (so Editor can use the full screen height) but never show them at the same time as the triple Editor/Panel/SideBar does not fit the screen.

Alternatively it will be nice to show both Panel and Sidebar on the right, but with Panel below Side Bar, but that I guess is just not supported by VS Code.

Comment: You can drag anything out of the Panel and into the Side Bar.  So you  could simulate the Panel "beneath" the Side Bar.  Just drag by the Panel view titles, like `Search` or `Terminal`.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware that it was possible to drag items from the panel into the activity bar (but that has to be show first). That pretty much solves the issue :) Although it will be nice to have terminal below, say, file explorer, having everything shown in the side bar is good enough.